# is there a way to write "If Greater than" and "If less than" statement in VUE html?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, vue.js

I've stumbled upon a problem recently, to which I've found a temporary solution.

I'd like to know whether it's possible to write a statement like,

```
If(a>b)
```

in HTML...

I'm currently working in vue.js, and I've found a temporary solution in `v-if` with `&`, `||`, `!` operators, but greater than or less than doesn't work (which is a permanent solution to my problem).

Here's my temporary solution:

```
v-if="models[0].paidDate.contains('2018') || models[0].paidDate.contains('2019') || models[0].paidDate.contains('2017')"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have already used v-if, so you should have realized that you can use less than or greater than operators :) Please see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have mentioned you're using Vue.js, I think what you're after is conditional rendering:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

You can do what you have asked like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <p v-if="number > 5">{{number}} is greater than 5</p>
  <p v-else>{{number}} is less than 5</p>
</div>


<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        number: 2
      }
    });
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/0q5ynm4d/1/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nimeshka, this is exactly what i was looking for...thank you so much

Comment: oh sorry...I Forgot

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to write `<p v-if="a > b">` to [conditionally render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) the `<p>` element when `a` is greater than `b` (and similarly for `v-if="a < b"`).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      c: 3,
      d: 4
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-if="a > b">a is greater than b</p>
  <p v-else>a is less than or equal to b</p>
  
  <p v-if="c < d">c is less than d</p>
  <p v-else>c is greater than or equal to d</p>
</div>
```

Given your example, I'm assuming you're trying to compare two date strings by year (where `models[0].paidDate` is a date string). You'd have to convert that to a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object before doing the comparison:

```
<p v-if="new Date(models[0].paidDate).getFullYear() > 2017">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      models: [
        { paidDate: '2017-10-11T21:11:44.741Z' },
        { paidDate: '2018-01-02T11:15:30.233Z' },
        { paidDate: '2016-05-23T09:19:25.445Z' },
        { paidDate: '2015-08-03T20:47:54.777Z' },
        { paidDate: '2019-11-05T23:36:21.098Z' },
        { paidDate: '2020-09-19T08:22:10.112Z' },
      ]
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3>All Dates</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(model, index) in models">
      {{index}} - {{new Date(model.paidDate).toString()}}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Dates after 2017</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(model, index) in models" v-if="new Date(model.paidDate).getFullYear() > 2017">
      {{index}} - {{new Date(model.paidDate).toString()}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly, Tony. I'm trying to hide a certain block of code when the whole date contains a any value greater than 2016.
And yes, it's already being converted on C# side.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered above, you may go ahead and use conditional rendering as is within the template. However, your condition is not very straightforward and it takes some time to figure out what you're after. As Vue documentation suggests, consider using [Computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) in this case.

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Models:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="model in modelsInDateRange">
        {{model.name}}, paid on: {{model.paidDate}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
       startYear: 2016,
       endYear: 2017,
       models: [
          { paidDate: '2018-10-08', name: 'Model 2018'},
          { paidDate: '2017-10-08', name: 'Model 2017'},
          { paidDate: '2016-10-08', name: 'Model 2016'},
          { paidDate: '2015-10-08', name: 'Model 2015'},
      ]
    },
    computed: {
        modelsInDateRange() {
            return this.models.filter(this.modelInDateRange);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        modelInDateRange(model) {
           const year = new Date(model.paidDate).getFullYear();
           if (year >= this.startYear && year <= this.endYear) {
              return true;
           }
           return false;
        }
    },
});
</script>
```

I made the example a bit more thorough to show the overall idea. In the template I loop through array of models that results from the filter method in the computed property. That relies on a method that determines whether the model falls into the specified date or not. You can find the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dan_elision/cLzfanjv/).

Comment: Thank you so much, Dan. Your solution is very helpful, gave me alot. I'm running the DotNet framework over here...thanks alot.